# Redirect iPhone to another URL with ASP.NET 3.5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone

How do you check if the user browsing my website is using an iPhone, and then redirect the user to another URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
if(Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("iPhone") > 0)
    Response.Redirect("~/iPhone/");
```

The iPhone's user-agent is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) 
AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3
```

Comment: Why iPhone > 0? 
Isn't it iPhone = true?

Comment: @Fogh: `IndexOf` returns the index of the string.  You could also write `if (Request.UserAgent.Contains("iPhone")`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Request.UserAgent` variable for the string `iPhone`. The entire string would look something  like this:

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) 
AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3
```

Comment: You mis-capitalized the string.